# Wrapper script that write logs of arguments, stdin and stdout

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to create a wrapper script which writes logs of arguments, stdin and stdout.
I have written the following script `wrapper.sh`, which works almost fine.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

wrapped_command="/path/to/command" # Set the path to the command which we want to wrap

log_dir="/tmp/stdio-log"
mkdir -p $log_dir

args_logfile=$log_dir/args
stdin_logfile=$log_dir/stdin
stdout_logfile=$log_dir/stdout
stderr_logfile=$log_dir/stderr

echo "$@" > "$args_logfile"

tee -a "$stdin_logfile" |
    "$wrapped_command" "$@" > >(tee -a "$stdout_logfile") 2> >(tee -a "$stderr_logfile" >&2)
```

I expect that `./wrapper.sh arg1 arg2` gives the same result as `/path/to/command arg1 arg2` with logs in `/tmp/stdio-log/`.
But it gives a slightly different result in Example 2 below.

#### Example 1: a command that accepts standard inputs

```sh
#! /bin/bash

while read line
do
    echo "input: $line"
done
```

The above wrapper script works as expected with this example.

#### Example 2: a command that does not accept standard inputs

```sh
#! /bin/bash
echo "Example command"
```

With this example, I got the following different behavior:

1. `/path/to/command` exits immediately.
2. `./wrapper.sh` does not exit immediately. I must type `<Return>` once to finish `wrapper.sh`.

### Question

How can I fix the wrapper script (or rewrite with different methods) so that it works as expected with both examples simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The in the foreground invoked `tee -a "$stdin_logfile"` waits for input.

> How can I fix the wrapper script …?

It works as you expect if *stdin* is handled just like *stdout* with [*Process Substitution*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

```
"$wrapped_command" "$@" < <(tee -a "$stdin_logfile")\
                        > >(tee -a "$stdout_logfile") 2> >(tee -a "$stderr_logfile" >&2)
```